# Who replaces "Was für ein" by "Was ein"?

Tags: dialect

I'm a native German speaker from Austria, but cannot tell (or find online) **which German dialect** tends to replace, for example,

> Was für ein schönes Auto!

with the shorter form

> Was ein schönes Auto!

I usually see this construction in informal communication. Is it a form of dialect from a specfic region?

Comment: I didn't think that "Was ein" is dialectal. You certainly say that in Western Germany. – "Welch ein" is quite uncommon here. It sounds even a bit odd to me. I'm not saying wrong, just a little odd. I would even drop "ein", when I were to use "welch" -> "Welch schönes Auto"

Comment: Ca. 53000 Google-Treffer allein für "was ein Spaß" sind sicher mehr als _a handful of people_. In Ruhr- / norddeutschen / plattdeutschen Dialekten scheint "Watt'n + Nomen" die "Übersetzung" zu sein für "Was für ein + Nomen". **Spekulation**: ist "Was ein + Nomen" eine Art 1:1-Rückübersetzung aus diesen Dialekten, also sozusagen Dialekt-Grammatik mit hochdeutschen Lauten?

Comment: @Matthias Danke, ich habe das "handvoll" rausgenommen.

Comment: Meinem Empfinden nach verbreitet sich "was ein(e)" in letzter Zeit auch im Süden. Vielleicht auch unter Einfluss des Englischen "what a".

Comment: Ich finde es interessant, dass hier gleich mehrere Bezüge zur Englischen Sprache hergestellt werden. Ich habe nicht den Eindruck, dass der durchschnittliche Deutsche so nahe an der Englischen Sprache ist. Vielleicht täusche ich mich.

Comment: Wenn deine Muttersprache Deutsch ist, und du in einem Deutsch-Forum eine Frage über einen Aspekt der deutschen Sprache stellst, und wenn du damit rechnen musst, dass andere Menschen mit Deutsch als Muttersprache deine Frage beantworten (weil 95 % aller Antworten von deutschen Muttersprachlern kommen), warum stellst du diese Frage dann in einer Fremdsprache?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Mein Eindruck war, dass es sich hier um ein international gelesenes Forum handelt (inbesondere wegen des Titels, German Language Beta). Gerade Fragen zur Umgangsprache sind auch für Leute relevant, deren Muttersprache nicht Deutsch ist. Ein signifikanter Teil der Fragen wird auf Englisch gestellt.

Comment: @painfulenglish: Gerade Fragen zur Umgangssprache sind vor allem für Personen interessant, die so gut Deutsch können, dass sie Fragen und Antworten in deutscher Sprache verstehen können. Auch zu bedenken ist, dass Menschen die kein Englisch sprechen auch Deutsch lernen dürfen, und dieses Forum sollte auch für sie verständlich sein. Die gemeinsame Sprache aller Besucher dieses Forums ist nicht Englisch, sondern Deutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ein sehr zutreffender Kommentar, insbesondere bzgl. der gemeinsamen Sprache. Werde ich in Zukunft beherzigen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to *Duden – Deutsches Universalwörterbuch*, 5. Aufl. Mannheim 2003, the expression *„was ein“* (in the given context) is colloquial for *„was für ein“* or *„welch ein“*:

> du weißt doch selbst, was ein Aufwand das ist
>   was ’n fieser Kerl!
>   was ’n Glück!

Hence, „was ein“ is correct and it is not necessarily dialect.

Comment: "correct" in the sense of colloquial, hopefully ;)

Comment: @Loong So the Duden does not mention any particular region where that construction is used?

Answer (score 2):

As dialects tends to simplify things (würde-Konjunktiv, less relative clauses, smaller vocabulary, evasion of genitive etc.), it wouldn't surprise me if this construction were one of these simplifications. It is difficult to find out (I didn't) to which dialects in particular this simplification pertains, since it's a grammatical construction, rather than a single word. But this construction, applied to some arbitrary dialects - regardless of whether or not it's already in use there -, seems perfectly understandable:

> Watt 'n Kack.
>   Wos a Oasch.
>   (Was ein Glück.)

Most strikingly, this construction is standard English

> What a surprise.

Judging from this, omitting the *für* seems to be a natural move. Probably because in its modern meaning(s) (200$ for a beautiful car/for you), *für* doesn't really make sense here, thus becoming dispensable. Still, in German, the omission remains colloquial.

Answer (score 0):

Vielleicht sollte die Frage eher umgekehrt lauten, in welchen Regionen wird "wasn(e)" wegen Hyperkorrektion durch "was ein(e)" und "was für ein(e)" ersetzt.

Immerhin ist Latein "quod" eine flektierte Form (nominative neuter singular) von "qui", wenn als Preposition auftretend-- was quasi auch bei diesem "was" der Fall ist. quod erat demonstrantum.

Neben "wasn Unsinn" findet sich auch "ist das ein Unsinn", "so ein Unsinn", "solcher Unsinn", "welch' Unsinn" und Varianten, "Es ist dies Unsinn", "dieser Unsinn schon wieder", und vorallem standardsprachlich *ohne "ein"* darin: **"Das ist _ Unsinn"**.

"wasn" findet sich nebenbei auch als "was denn?", sächsisch etwa "wassene?", das syntaktisch und morphemisch nunmehr eben genauso wenig einleuchtet wie "was für ein" und als feststehendes Idiom im Lexikon steht.

Ein *-n* findet sich auch--sicherlich nicht zufällig--in *wessen*, *wann*, *wohin*, *woran*, *wogegen* und *wen*. Am bemerkenswertesten ist aber wohl *wem*, da equivalent mit "was für einem", und der direktional Sinn von *für* hier wenigstens dem Genitiv entsprechend sinnvoll ist.

Flektiert werden auch die Preposition "vor ~ vorn", "hinter ~ hinten", *fern ~ fort*, etc. bemerkenswert einerseits da "vor" verwandt mit "für", "pro", "per", etc ist, sowie weil "ich geh nach vorn" einem Pronomen für "die Spitze, die Front, der Anfang, etc." gleicht, bzw. damit kontrastiert, vgl. "Ich gehe zu Ihr".

Das ist viel Gewese, nur um zu sagen, man sollte mal gucken ob die Wurzel von "was" eine n-Wurzelerweiterung aufweist.

Edit: Nachdem ich dies umgehend nachgeschlagen habe, finde ich zwar keine n-Erweiterung im Urgermanischen unter [*hwat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/hwat) oder weiter zurück, aber eine vielversprechende Ableitung

> #### Norwegisch (Nynorsk) [kven](https://nn.wiktionary.org/wiki/kven)
>
> Frå norrønt hverr, **akkusativ eintal** hannkjønn hvern.
>
> ##### Pronomen
>
> 1. spørjeord nytta i direkte spørsmål; **kva for ein person**.
>
> Kven har du snakka med? [Wen hast du gesprochen mit?]
>
> 2. spørjeord nytta i usjølvstendige spørjesetningar.
>
> Eg veit ikkje kven dette er. [Ich weiß nicht **???** das ist]
>
> <sub>Hervorhebung und Übersetzung meine. Ich weiß tatsächlich nicht, weshalb google-translate verschiedentlich De. "was", En. "but", "sequencer" übersetzt, ich spreche keinen Deut Norwegisch.</sub>

Die soll eher als Biespiel dienen, nicht als die Wurzel allen Übels.

PS: Besonders hervorben möchte ich noch *watn datn?* quasi "was ist das [denn]?", aus'm Raum Berlin (¿*ausn rau'n Berlin*?). Es ist wohl bekannt, dass *nu* ursprachlich bspw. gotisch als Fragewort stand.

Answer (score -4):

„Was für ein schönes Auto“ ist Hochdeutsch.
„Was ein schönes Auto“ ist noch immer Hochdeutsch, bedeutet aber das Gleiche.
Dialekt wäre z. B. „Wadd ’n schönes Auto“ oder „Desch ’n schönes Auto“.

Comment: "Was ein schönes Auto" mag richtig sein wenn es z.B. am Anfang von "Was ein schönes Auto ausmacht" steht. Aber den Ausruf "Was ein schönes Auto!" hätte ich keinesfalls als richtiges Deutsch eingeschätzt.

Comment: Ich muss zugeben "Was ein schönes Auto" habe ich ebenfalls noch nie gehört, dass gilt aber auch für "Was für ein schönes Auto". "Was für ein schönes Auto" klingt für mich jedoch logischer, zumindest in geschriebener Form.
Die Frage bezieht sich aber auf einen Dialekt, ich wollte nur verdeutlichen, dass weder "Was für.." noch "Was ein.." einen Dialekt darstellt. Du könntest aber sagen "Was'n schönes Auto", dann wäre es bayrisch. "Was'n" ist kurz für "Was ein".

Comment: Das 'n muss nicht unbedingt von *ein* stammen. Immerhin ist *welchen, welcher* auch regelmäßig flektiert. Was hier wierum voraus ging lässt sich schlecht sagen. *Was für ein ...*, "what for a load of ..." ist für mich überhaupt nicht logisch.

Answer (score -4):

Ich hab zwar schon eineAntwort geschrieben, aber doppelt hält besser. In diesem Theil möchte ich tiefer darauf eingehen, dass *was für ein* rein semantologisch auch gar kein Sinn ergibt. Die Herkunft dessen scheint mir ungeklärt.

Weil *f* < /v/ sinnvoll wäre, während Rhotazismus (*r* < *s*) arbitraer erscheint, ist lateinisch *quisquis* "irgendwas" der naheliegnde Schluss. Die ursprachliche Realität wird durch Vergleich mit Tocharisch wahrscheinlich gemacht.

Das war's auch schon.